# How to configure GnuPG's S.gpg-agent socket location?

Tags: 16.04, configuration, gnupg

GnuPG places its socket `S.gpg-agent` at `~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent` by default. I didn't find any way to configure the location of this socket nor seems there to be a manpage of `gpg.conf`.

Background: I want to symlink `~/.gnupg` to an OpenAFS mount which doesn't support sockets (and avoid to create a symlink for every file in `~/.gnupg` (which is a workaround) instead of just `~/.gnupg`), i.e. find the most elegant solution imo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User ruhri's solution did not work for us on our Debian stretch systems. At least, we had to add more socket "redirects". Here is what worked for us.

1. Create the `.gnupg/S.gpg-agent` file as described by ruhri:

   ```
   %Assuan%
   socket=/srv/scratch/joeuser/S.gpg-agent
   ```
2. Add these two lines to the end of `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` (create file if it does not already exist):

   ```
   extra-socket /srv/scratch/joeuser/S.gpg-agent.extra
   browser-socket /srv/scratch/joeuser/S.gpg-agent.browser
   ```
3. Create the file `.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh` similar to the file `.gnupg/S.gpg-agent`:

   ```
   %Assuan%
   socket=/srv/scratch/joeuser/S.gpg-agent.ssh
   ```

This solution comes from [this comment](https://michaelheap.com/gpg-cant-connect-to-the-agent-ipc-connect-call-failed/).

Answer (score 7):

Since GnuPG Version 2.1.1 there exists a solution:
Place a simple text-file S.gpg-agent in the gpg-homedir with following content:

```
%Assuan%
socket=/path/to/where/ever/you/want/S.gpg-agent
```

It replaces some evnvars like `${HOME}` or `${HOSTNAME}`

Be careful, when using a subdirectory of `/tmp`, because gpg-agent will not create  needed directories.

Further reading at:
https://dev.gnupg.org/T1752

Comment: This no longer works, cf. http://bugs.debian.org/935966

Comment: Unfortunately, for Windows, it never did. In assuan-socket.c in libassuan, it has "#ifndef HAVE_W32 SYSTEM" around that functionality. I could really use that functionality right now.